# Print sql data grouped in a single row, without repeating row

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, list, sqlite

Premise that i'm still looking for other solutions, my data is printed like this and the rows are tripled:

```
('iMac 24', '24', 'Apple', 8)
('iMac 24', '24', 'Apple', 9)
('iMac 24', '24', 'Apple', 10)
('HP 24', '24-Cb1033nl', 'HP', 7)
('HP 24', '24-Cb1033nl', 'HP', 6)
('HP 24', '24-Cb1033nl', 'HP', 7)
```

I want to print them in one rows and group the votes. So I would like to get:

```
('iMac 24', '24', 'Apple', [8, 9, 10])  
('HP-24', '24-Cb1033nl', 'HP', [7, 6, 7])
```

My code is:

```
mydb = cursor_test.execute("SELECT product, model, creator, vote FROM sales")

for row in mydb.fetchall():
    print(row)
```

The output of this code is the one shown above where the products triple

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a GROUP_CONCAT like this (I'll be guessing the column names as they're not provided):

```
SELECT 
  pc_model_name, 
  pc_model_number, 
  pc_brand, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(grade)
FROM computers
GROUP BY 
  pc_model_name, 
  pc_model_number, 
  pc_brand
```

If you want to learn more about GROUP_CONCAT in case you need to tweak it a bit, you can read up on it on this website: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group_concat/

Comment: Thank you. Now I have to go to sleep. I'll text your code tomorrow and get back to you tomorrow

Comment: Alright, do let me know if it works. Cheers.

Comment: the equivalent of group_concat() in postgresql is array_agg()

Answer (score 0):

`defaultdict` might be a great tool in your case.

```py
from collection import defaultdict

grade_dict = defaultdict(list)
for entry in mydb.fetchall():
    grade_dict[entry[:3]].append(entry[3])
    
result = [(key[0], key[1], key[2], grades) for key, grades in grade_dict.items()]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[('iMac 24', '24', 'Apple', [8, 9, 10]), 
('HP 24', '24-Cb1033nl', 'HP', [7, 6, 7])]
```

You can also make a good use of `groupby`. This approach is more efficient because it does not require the creation of intermediate dictionary and also it uses a generator expression to create the list of grades which is more memory-efficient.

```py
from itertools import groupby

result = [(key, [grade for _, _, _, grade in group]) for key, group in groupby(mydb.fetchall(), lambda x: x[:3])]
result = [(key[0], key[1], key[2], values) for key, values in result]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[('iMac 24', '24', 'Apple', [8, 9, 10]), 
('HP 24', '24-Cb1033nl', 'HP', [7, 6, 7])]
```

Comment: Maybe that's not quite the solution I was looking for. I need something simple but also speed and performance, because I have to manage thousands of rows in the db and dictionaries. Maybe defaultdict is also fast, I don't know, but I need something simpler. Can you ALSO show me a second simpler solution without defaultdict please? (without deleting the solution with defaultdict). However, my key must be product only. The values are model, creator and vote

Comment: I provided another approach which is more efficient.

Comment: Thank you. Now I have to go to sleep. I'll text your code tomorrow and get back to you tomorrow